# Scheduled Tasks is not working

Tags: php, linux, scheduled-tasks, plesk

taskmanager.php is working when I try it myself. but I cant set it. System user is root user. there is no problem with the permissions. But its not working its not open `taskmanager.php`

I tried this command.

```
php /var/www/vhosts/pornmerkezi.com/httpdocs/admin/taskmanager.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Tk1.png

I tried this command too but still not working.

```
/var/www/vhosts/pornmerkezi.com/httpdocs/admin/taskmanager.php
```